# Connected $T_2$-spaces with only constant maps between them

Tags: gn.general-topology, examples

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is continuous, then it is constant. Are there infinite connected $T_2$-spaces $X,Y$ such that the only continuous maps $f:X\to Y$ are the constant maps?

Comment: Is a $T_2$ space just an obscure (to me) way of saying a Hausdorff space?

Comment: Apparently there's an example of a countable connected Hausdorff space such that if you remove a point it becomes totally disconnected. So how about letting $X$ be the reals and letting $Y$ be this? Might work. I've had a look at some of the examples constructed in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-026-02/S0002-9939-1970-0263005-0/S0002-9939-1970-0263005-0.pdf and they're pretty weird.

Comment: You might also be interested in the paper Horst Herrlich: [Wann sind alle stetigen Abbildungen in Y konstant?](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01112240) Mathematische Zeitschrift, Volume 90, Number 2, 152-154
Also freely available at [GDZ](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0090&DMDID=dmdlog25). The results from this paper are summarized in this Math.SE post: [Existence of non-constant continuous functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72442).

Comment: There are plenty of examples of **compact** connected metric spaces $Y$ (classical or hand-made) for which only continuous maps of $I$ into $Y$ are constant. More fun would be to get also compact connected metric spaces $X$ such that the only continuous maps from one space to another, and in the other direction, are all constant.

Comment: Dominic, do you have a copy of Counterexamples in Topology in your library? If not, then it would seem (based on the general trend of your questions) to be a valuable book to acquire. It's published by Dover, so pretty inexpensive (from where I stand, less than 10 US dollars).

Comment: Incidentally, I think Włodzimierz in his first sentence might be referring to *pseudo-arcs*, which are kind of a canonical example (well worth knowing about). They are strange critters, but strangely commonplace in a mathematical sense (the same way everywhere nondifferentiable continuous curves are commonplace). A classical reference is by Bing: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102613150

Comment: I will add to @ToddTrimble's comment that most a lot of data from the book [Counterexamples in Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) is also included in [pi-base](http://topology.jdabbs.com/), which is an online database of topological spaces and their properties. For various combinations of topological properties it is very easy to search for the spaces in the database which have them. (Although I am not sure whether it would actually help with this particular question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any real-valued function on the positive integers with the prime integer topology (subbasis of sets of the form $U_p(b)=\{b+np:n\in \mathbb{Z}, p\nmid b\}$) is constant. This is on [page 82](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gc3DAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA82) of [Counterexamples in Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology); item 4 shows that this topology is $T_2$ and item $7$ both constancy of real-valued functions and connectedness.

Answer (score 1):

Another example: let $X=[0,1]$ and let $Y\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ be the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan). Both are connected and Hausdorff, but the path components of $Y$ are points, so any map $f:X\to Y$ must be constant.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing Dejan Govc's answer...

In this paper http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-032-02/S0002-9939-1972-0296913-7/S0002-9939-1972-0296913-7.pdf it is shown that every continuous function from a connected and locally connected space into a connected space with a dispersion point is constant. It's easy to prove actually.